# FBX exporting error

Tags: modeling, animation, export, unity

I am trying to export a model as a .fbx I've done exactly as I have for other models and for some reason I am getting an error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
[image: Export Error]

Comment: This needs to be reported as a bug to [the tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug), with the .blend file to reproduce it. Assuming you are using latest version of Blender, obviously.